# REST API requested with curl returns 404 error

Tags: rest, rundeck

I used to request the REST API with curl or perl-ish LWP.
This works :

```
curl -S -L -c cookies -b cookies -d j_username=admin -d j_password="*******" https://ordo.in.phm.education.gouv.fr/j_security_check
```

and shows me the Dashboard, assuring that I'm authenticated, but this :

```
curl -S -L -c cookies -b cookies -H 'Accept: application/json'  https://ordo.in.phm.education.gouv.fr/api/14/system/info
```

returns a 404 error, not an "unauthenticated" nor a "api mismatch" error

It used to works, in fact I borrowed these lines from a code I wrote and successfully used last year

Thanks

Cheers,

Xavier

Comment: 404 implies the endpoint youre trying to access could not be found. Could the API have changed in the year since you wrote the code?

Comment: I just updated RD from 3.1.x to 3.2

Answer (score 0):

On this way return OK code (200):

```
curl -v -c cookie -b cookie -d j_username=user -d j_password=password http://your-rundeck-instance:4440/j_security_check -H "Accept: application/json" http://your-rundeck-instance:4440/api/34/system/info/
```

Tested under Rundeck 3.2.1